# Pointing a subdomain at a file

Tags: linux, subdomain

Switched hosting recently (Linux, CPanel, WHM). At the old host, there was a subdomain that had a file (instead of a directory) as a root. The file was a CGI script. The said subdomain was created via CPanel by me a while ago.

At the new host, I'm trying to recreate this subdomain. And I get the following error:

> The directory,
>   /home/(...)/cgi-bin/guest.cgi could
>   not be created.

Is there a tweak somewhere that enables this functionality?

EDIT: tried to repeat the trick on the old site, and I could not. CPanel update broke it, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you had an `.htaccess` on the subdomain created that leads the user to `guest.cgi` with a internal redirect ?

AFAIK cpanel subdomain will create the subdomain folder, so for example:

Our domain will be domain.com and our subdomain will be test

cPanel will create the subdomain for you and a default structure folder at the root of domain.com:
/home/domain.com/test

Now you make a simple .htaccess file inside test with the follow content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/guest.cgi$
RewriteRule . cgi-bin/guest.cgi [L]
```

The above file will redirect any request made to test.domain.com to be redirected to `cgi-bin/guest.cgi` !

Perhaps you had something like this on your subdomain... you can use a simple redirect in php aswell if you wish, make a index.php on the test.domain.com with the content:

```
<?
Header( "Location: http://test.domain.com/cgi-bin/guest.cgi" );
?>
```

Comment: I just checked .htaccess in the cgi-bin folder - it was not like this. But then again, it could've been implemented via upper-level Apache configs. I don't have root rights on that box.

Comment: @Seva it is not inside cgi-bin that the .htaccess should be but inside the root folder.

Comment: it could be anywhere up the tree to the root or in the /etc configs.

Comment: @pjz cgi-bin folders usually have httpd.conf rules which may get overwritten so it would not work and ALSO he wants the root test.domain.com to get to test.domain.com/cgi-bin/guest.cgi so if that .htaccess is inside the cgi-bin forlder it would never work.